# How to exclude MixtureDistribution from FindDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

is there a way to exclude `MixtureDistribution` from the set of fitted distributions when using `FindDistribution`?

I expected that `TargetFunctions` option within `FindDistribution` would resolve this, however `MixtureDistribution` still comes up as a proposed candidate -  though the component distributions within the proposed MixtureDistribution are indeed restricted to those listed in `TargetFunctions`.

Cheers,

td

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of a method to exclude [`MixtureDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixtureDistribution.html) from [`FindDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html).  However, if you want to test individual distributions to your data then you may use [`EstimatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html). This function does not return any statistics on the fit but you can use [`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) on its result to test for goodness of fit.

If there is some data,

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{.7, .3}, 
        {ParetoDistribution[500, 20, 0], HalfNormalDistribution[.25]}];
SeedRandom[789];
data = RandomVariate[dist, 1000];
```

That results in a `MixtureDistribution` where you wish to exclude this form.

```
FindDistribution[data, 
 TargetFunctions -> {InverseGaussianDistribution, 
   HalfNormalDistribution, LevyDistribution, LogNormalDistribution}]
```

> ```
> MixtureDistribution[{0.866903, 0.133097}, 
>  {LogNormalDistribution[1.95719, 1.43364], 
>   LogNormalDistribution[3.82415, 0.414689]}]
> ```

Then map `EstimateDistribution` and `DistributionFitTest` over the distributions

```
htd = DistributionFitTest[data, EstimatedDistribution[data, #], "HypothesisTestData"] & /@ 
  {InverseGaussianDistribution[a, b], 
   HalfNormalDistribution[a], 
   LevyDistribution[a, b], 
   LogNormalDistribution[a, b]}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Goodness of fit statistics are available in each [`HypothesisTestData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypothesisTestData.html) object. Use this information to select the best fit.

```
fitted = First@MaximalBy[Select[#["PValue"] >= 0.05 &]@htd, #["PValue"] &, 1];
fitted["TestConclusion"]
fitted["FittedDistribution"]
```

> ```
> The null hypothesis that the data is distributed according to the 
>  LogNormalDistribution[2.16635,1.39778] is not rejected at the 5 percent level 
>  based on the Cramér-von Mises test.
>
> LogNormalDistribution[2.16635, 1.39778]
> ```

Additional `fitted` properties are listed with `fitted["Properties"]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should really read the docs better. I'd never seen [`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) before, but have wanted it at many points in time.

Comment: Hi Edmund that does help - thanks for the work around.